# How do you interpret the matrix confusion in this Naïve Bayes output?

Tags: machine-learning, naive-bayes, weka

Why are my correctly classified instances lower than incorrectly classified?

This was tested using Naive Bayes with option testing Cross-Validation set at 10 folds.

Here is the image of the results: [Naive Bayes Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngbQQ.png)

Comment: Interpret what?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to CV! Can you ask what exactly you don't understand? For example, did you not understand why the precision for bmw is 0.531, based on the given confusion matrix? You should give some pointers of what you don't understand in this picture, surely one shouldn't explain every detail in it for you. Besides, results being good or not is subjective.

Comment: A confusion matrix should have the same interpretation, no matter how you generate the classifications. What about naïve Bayes is special here?